# Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not match the expected pattern

Tags: python

I know there are some similar questions on this site but I can't seem to figure what's wrong here. In my small app from a html file I call a python file that returns a json.

html file:

```
fetch('readjobs.py')
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(job => {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${job[1]}</td>
            `;
            document.querySelector('#jobTable tbody').appendChild(row);
            });
        });
```

python file:

```
import mysql.connector
import json

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="sdfsgfgd",
  database="mydb"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT LINK, JOB_TITLE FROM jobs")
data = mycursor.fetchall()
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
print("Content-Type: application/json")
print("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
print()
print(json.dumps(data))
```

An example of the dump:

```
[["link1", "Wizard"], ["link2", "Superman"]]
```

Since this is a valid json, I have no idea what's wrong.

In Safari this is the error message:

> [Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: SyntaxError: The string did not
> match the expected pattern.   promiseEmptyOnRejected
> promiseReactionJob

In Chrome this is it:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'i', "import
> mys"... is not valid JSON

Comment: Your webserver appears to be returning the *contents of the python file* rather than the result of running it as a script. Did you put it in your static assets folder? How are you serving your webpage?

Comment: You need to put the script in a CGI directory, or configure the webserver to execute python using CGI.

Comment: If you want to use Python in your webserver, it would be a good idea to learn Flask.

Comment: @JaredSmith I went the easy way and placed the .py file next to the .html file in /var/www/html

Comment: @erdomester it sounds like you're possibly using apache then. I would follow Barmar's suggestion of using Flask to serve your Python script as a REST endpoint and have apache proxy to it.